# Calculus Integration, using the substitution method

Tags: calculus

[image: Please help solve using substitution method]

Please help solve this problem using the u-substitution method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, have you tried a substitution?

Comment: Yes, multiple times. However I cannot quite pick the right function to represent 'u' in order to cancel out the 'x' values.

Comment: $2xdx=dx^{2}$ bells ringing?

Comment: No bells ringing, have just started integration, the only tools I have to solve are the reverse of the power rule and u-substitution. Wolfram Alpha has gone off into inserting trig identities, what I am looking for is a framework I can apply to approach this problem and future ones... At this stage I get to the point where 8∫x(x^2-1)(2x^2-3)^-(1/2)dx... Thus far I have been able to get by looking for the derivative of one of the functions and cancelling out the x values, however I have been unable to successfully do so this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the change : $2 x^2 - 3 = y^2$. The integral becomes very simple.

Comment: Thank you very much, thank was exactly the hint needed - it has helped a lot. My final answer keeps coming up as 4/3(2x^2-3)+(2x^2-3)^(1/2)+C however the back of the book advises 4/3*x^2(2x^2-3)^(1/2)+C. I will continue working through it tomorrow. Thanks again

Comment: @James Assuming that $2x^2-3$ is not in the denominator, you could clear the parentheses and add to C to form a new constant.  Both answers would be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the change $2x^2-3=y^2,$ you have to integrate $(2+2y^2)dy$ which is effectively very simple. After the integration, replace $y$ by its expression as a function of $x$ and continue simplifying. You then arrive to $$\frac{4x^2 \sqrt{2x^2-3}}{3},$$ this is what tells your book .
Add the integration constant to make your book happy ! Simple, isn't ? I am glad to have been able to help you.

Comment: @user376343. and again ...